# C# Each instance of class needs different method

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a static class with number of different methods.

I have another class, and with each instance of this class, I would like it to have a method which calls one of the methods in the static class. For each instance, I want be able to specify which of the methods it will use via the constructor of this class.

Is there a simple way to do this? Should I be using delegates/interfaces?

Comment: You *might* get some purchase out of multicast delegates. But if you could post some code, that would help. Better design may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the methods all have the same signature? If so, a delegate would certainly be a good approach... although it wouldn't *restrict* the caller to passing in a method group from the static class. If that's not a problem, here's a sample:

```
using System;

public static class TestMethods
{
    public static void Foo(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo " + x);
    }

    public static void Bar(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar " + x);
    }
}

public class DummyClass
{
    private readonly Action<int> action;

    public DummyClass(Action<int> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void CallAction(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            action(i);
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DummyClass d1 = new DummyClass(TestMethods.Foo);
        DummyClass d2 = new DummyClass(TestMethods.Bar);
        d1.CallAction(2, 4);
        d2.CallAction(3, 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Causix - If the methods don't have the same signatures, your single class is not going to know how to call each one without using some reflection. You might wanna pass a `MethodInfo` rather than a delegate. Perhaps you should post some code samples so we can see clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
public delegate void MyStaticMethodInvoker(params object[] values);

public class TestStatic
{
    public static void TestMethod1(params object[] values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestMethod1 invoked");
    }

    public static void TestMethod2(params object[] values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestMethod2 invoked");
    }

    public static void TestMethod3(params object[] values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestMethod3 invoked");
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    private MyStaticMethodInvoker _targetMethod;

    public TestClass(MyStaticMethodInvoker targetMethod)
    {
        _targetMethod = targetMethod;
    }

    public void CallTargetedStaticMethod()
    {
        _targetMethod.Invoke(1,2,3,4);
    }
}
```

And then you can create instances of TestClass and in constructor define target static method:

```
TestClass tc1 = new TestClass(new MyStaticMethodInvoker(TestStatic.TestMethod1));
tc1.CallTargetedStaticMethod();

TestClass tc2 = new TestClass(new MyStaticMethodInvoker(TestStatic.TestMethod2));
tc2.CallTargetedStaticMethod();

TestClass tc3 = new TestClass(new MyStaticMethodInvoker(TestStatic.TestMethod3));
tc3.CallTargetedStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Why are you using `new MyStaticMethodInvoker(TestStatic.TestMethod3)` instead of a method group conversion of just `TestStatic.TestMethod3`?

Comment: To point out that delegate is used in this case. Yep, a same affect is by using TestClass tc1 = new TestClass(TestStatic.TestMethod1);

Comment: Thanks for this, I don't quite understand it all at the moment so I'll go with what Skeet said for now. It's given me food for thought though. +1